# Where to put view logic?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, view, partial

I am a little confused regarding the design patterns of ASP.NET MVC. I have a Masterpage including a partial view that renders breadcrumbs:

```
<div id="header">
    <strong class="logo"><a href="#">Home</a></strong>
    <% Html.RenderPartial("BreadCrumbs"); %>
```

The thing is, I want the breadcrumb links to work both in production and in my dev environment. So my code in the partial view goes something like this:

```
<p id="breadcrumbs">
    You are here: <a href="http://
    <% if (Request.Url.IsLoopback)
           Response.Write(String.Format("{0}/{1}", Request.Url.Host, Request.Url.Segments[1]));
       else
           Response.Write("http://mysite.com/");

...
```

Is this violating the principle of keeping the view "stupid"? Part of my reasoning for extracting this from the masterpage was this principle. Seems that I just moved the problem over to a new view? What is the alternative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what MVC version you are using. If you are using MVC3, you could create a GlobalActionFilter: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx

```
public class ViewBagInjectionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);

        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.SiteUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.IsLoopback
                                                       ? String.Format("{0}/{1}",
                                                                       filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host,
                                                                       filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.
                                                                           Segments[1])
                                                       : "http://mysite.com/";

    }
}
```

This filter could then add a property into your ViewBag (which is a dynamic object), called `SiteUrl`, in which you set the site url depending on the state you are in.

In your PartialView you would no longer need the `if` statement, and just call: `ViewBag.SiteUrl` . In addition any other page will have access to the SiteUrl property.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the generation of the breadcrumbs in a child action. This will give you a whole new View and Controller

In the masterpage:

```
 <%: Html.Action("Crumbs", "Master") %>
```

MasterController:

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
 public PartialViewResult Crumbs() {
    if (Request.Url.IsLoopback()) {
       return PartialView("DebugCrumbs");
    } else {
       return PartialView("Crumbs");
    }
 }
```

Create a Crumbs and DebugCrumbs view that will be called local or not.

Comment: Not really DRY, is it? Perhaps it would be better to create the Url in the controller, and pass it to the crumbs view. This way you have only one view.

Comment: @Gidon, Oh sure why not, but this means that the view must test include an extra test & logic. I like to call a view that contains as less content/logic as possible.

Comment: actually I propose doing the logic in the controller, and giving the passing the "calculated" URL into the view (using a [View]Model, ViewBag or ViewData)